# PHP macro / combine fields into one variable

Tags: php, variables, macros

I'm working with a custom made plugin that a company provides and I need to fill a variable with there fields.

The provide the following macro:

```
$voertuig->verkoopprijs_particulier->value();
```

I try to use that with this snippet:

```
$productprijs = $voertuig->verkoopprijs_particulier->value();
echo $productprijs;
```

(The echo is for testing, I'm using that variable elsewhere).

But the problem with that is, it does not generate correctly.
What I get is the following:
€ 1.900,-->value()

Any advise on how to get the full macro to be used in my variable?

Comment: It's difficult to know what it's doing without any source code to look at.

Comment: I'll dive into the code of the plugin. But what it is supposed to do is return the price with some conditions. In this case. The price just as value.

Is there any other way I can try to return the variable as wished?

Right now, it does nothing with the last part of the macro: ->value(); is returned as it is.

Comment: Solved, sorry. Turned out to be a bug inside the plugin, not the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a bug inside the plugin. Not the code. so solved.